# How to create a new file via touch if it is in a directory which doesn't exist?

Tags: command-line

Let's say the directory `~/this_dir` doesn't exist.

I need to be able to run `touch ~/this_dir/new.txt` to create `new.txt` in `~/this_dir`.

Is there a simple way to make touch also create the directory?

Or an alternative command which would achieve the same thing?

Thanks

Comment: There's no single system call that can create directories up to a new file, so generally these are different tasks that you can't do with a single invocation of any "traditional" command like `touch`, and I don't think `cp` will do this either.  The answer using `install` is neat, though, if you want efficiency in a script moreso than being obvious or clear to readers.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is the command `install` which will accomplish what you are asking for.

```
install -Dv /dev/null this_dir/new.txt
```

(source: [Bash command to create a new file and its parent directories if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24675139/1721265))

Explanation:

- `install` is used to copy files and set attributes (see `man install`)
- `-D` tells the command to "create all leading components of DEST except the last, or all components of --target-directory, then copy SOURCE to DEST"
- `-v` causes to show every creation step (can be omitted of course)
- `/dev/null` is the source, from where to copy
- `this_dir/new.txt` is the target of the copy operation.

---

@rchard2scout has thankfully pointed out that

> The install command is part of GNU Coreutils, which has been marked as "Essential". That means it'll basically always be available.

Comment: very nice explanation.. do we need to install the package 0r it out of the box? considering 18.04 19.04 19.10

Comment: Hey! After 30+ years working with UNIX and Linux, I still learn something new! Thanks.

Comment: @PRATAP The `install` command is part of [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/), which has been marked as "[Essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/coreutils)". That means it'll basically always be available.

Comment: @rchard2scout Hi, thanks.. after posting my comment, I have tried it and found it is out of the box in my 18.04 19.04 and 19.10. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This command is very often used in, e.g., spectemplates & other packages scripts.

Answer (score 22):

I would recommend use the `&&`.

Example:

```
mkdir ~/this_dir && touch ~/this_dir/new.txt
```

The `&&` deals accepts a new command. So `mkdir this_dir`, also do the rest.

This is very useful because can be used for everything, not only for new folders.

Comment: Also there's `mkdir -p ~/this_dir/that_dir && touch ~/this_dir/that_dir/new.txt`.

Comment: I like this solution because it is the most easy solution to understand for someone with just basic nix knowledge. It is also very descriptive of what is happening. :-)

Comment: **This fails if `~/this_dir` *does* exist**.  Use `mkdir -p` to fix that.  Or if that behaviour is on purpose, mention it in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution, given `$file` as a file, this should work:

```bsh
mkdir -p $(dirname $file) && touch $file
```

or even

```bsh
# create function
touchfile () {
    local file="$1"
    mkdir -p -- "$(dirname -- "$file")" &&
        touch -- "$file"
}

# then just
touchfile /path/to/file/to/touch/woah
```

Comment: Alternative (but not exactly via touch, though):

`mkdir {1..10}_directory && touch {1..10}_directory/FILENAME.txt`